# Animating a single View based on multiple ScrollView(s)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, animation, react-native

I'm working on an application where I'm trying to Animate a `View` based on scroll Position of multiple `ScrollView`s.

This is how the screen looks.

[image: Profile Screen]

The above screen has 2 parts

- A `View` component on Top
- A `TabNavigator` component at the Bottom

each tab in `TabNavigator` has a `ScrollView` in it (in this case there are 2 but can be more), What I want to achieve is to collapse the `View` as the user scrolls down and expand it when the user scrolls up. 
On a single Tab I was doing well, it was working exactly how I wanted it to do, but the problem came when I added the 2nd Tab.

**The Problem**

When I scroll a bit on tab1 and move to tab2 and try to scroll, it gets jerky. see the GIF to understand what I'm trying to say

[image: React Native Animation Jerk]

---

## Update

Check this snack on expo.io to see the problem live

[snack.expo.io/SytBkdBAW](https://snack.expo.io/SytBkdBAW)

---

**What I tried**

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      /* omitted - not related */
      scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)
    }
  }

  render () {

    let translateY = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 600],
      outputRange: [0, -290],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    });

    let TabsTranslateY = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 600],
      outputRange: [0, -290],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={{transform: [{translateY: translateY}], overflow: 'hidden'}}>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>
            Welcome to React Native!!
          </Text>

          <Text style={styles.time}>
            {this.state.hour} : {this.state.minute}
          </Text>

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { /* omitted */ }} style={styles.button}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Set Time</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.View style={{
          flex: 0,
          transform: [{translateY: TabsTranslateY}],
          height: Dimensions.get('window').height
        }}>
          <Tabs removeClippedSubviews={false} screenProps={{animatedScrollY: this.state.scrollY}}/>
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({/* omitted styles*/})
```

Home.js (Tab1)

```
/* omitted imports */
export default class Home extends Component {
  /* omitted navigation options */
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      scrollY: this.props.screenProps.animatedScrollY
    }

  }

  render () {
  return (
      <View>
        <Animated.ScrollView onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}],
          {useNativeDriver: true}
        )} scrollEventThrottle={16}>

          {Array(90).fill().map((v, i) => {
            return <Text key={i}
                         style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#333', padding: 20, marginVertical: 10, color: 'white'}}>Item
              #{i + 1}</Text>
          })}
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Photos.js (Tab2)

```
/* omitted imports */
export default class Photos extends Component {
  /* omitted navigation options */
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      PhotosScrollY: this.props.screenProps.animatedScrollY
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Animated.ScrollView onScroll={Animated.event(
        [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.PhotosScrollY}}}],
        {useNativeDriver: true}
      )} scrollEventThrottle={16}>

        <View style={{flex: 1,}}>
          {Array(90).fill().map((v, i) => {
            return <View key={i} style={/* omitted */}>
              <Text style={/* omitted */}>
                Photo #{i + 1}
              </Text>
            </View>
          })}
        </View>

      </Animated.ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to overcome this problem, Any suggestions and solutions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What if you use it directly from the props without assigning it to state?

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov You're talking about `animatedScrollY` right? - No I can't use in tabs directly from state because that's only available in App.js, and even if I were I don't  think that would change anything.

Comment: @Azeem Hassni, can you add your Tab.js file?

Comment: Sure you can check it in the snack https://snack.expo.io/SytBkdBAW  -> `/Tabs/index.js`

Comment: Say you open the app, scroll down a bit on the home tab, and then switch to the items tab. Should the items list be at the top? If so, and there's nowhere to scroll up to, how would you reveal the header?

Comment: @RobHogan you drag the ScrollView down to reveal the header. Actually I want to implement the exact experience of Twitter's profile screen. You can check this effect by navigating to a profile in Twitter's android app where the header is connected with multiple scrollviews.

Comment: This is an amazing library if you are looking for an effect like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-collapsible-tab-view

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [Animated.add()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/docs/animated.html#add)

So you need in `App`

```
const tab1ScrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
const tab2ScrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
const scrollY = Animated.add(tab1ScrollY,tab2ScrollY)
```

`scrollY` it's offset of `tab1 scroll` +  `tab2 scroll`

Comment: Thanks, This almost solves my problem except one thing, after scrolling on Tab1 when you navigate to Tab2 you can't scroll down so the header gets stuck, unless you move back to Tab1 and scroll. you can check this behavior here https://snack.expo.io/rJXwrLQ1G

Comment: If you've a solution to the problem I've specified in my comment. I'll accept the answer and reward the bounty points.

Comment: @AzeemHassni, have you got the solution for your problem(Header gets stuck)?

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue. I tried solving it this way. (Optimising it still..)

```
<ParentComponent>
    <CollapsibleHeader/>
    <TabNavigator/>
</ParentComponent>
```

The scrollState lies in Parent Component, and tabs inside TabNavigator has scrollView.
I update the state in the parent component using callback after binding the Animation event.

So whenever you move between two tabs, the state lies in the parent component and it is updated from a different place.

May be this could help you.

NOTE: Still optimising it.

---------Edit--------

Parent Component:

state: `scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)`

```
componentDidMount(){
    binding event.
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    Unbind event.
}
onScrollEventCaptured(){
  (update parent state and send it to <CollapsibleHeader/>)*
}
```

Tab 1:
This has local state. (Optimising this part)
,scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)

Has a ListView

onScroll function on ListView:

```
onScroll={Animated.event([{
                        nativeEvent: {
                            contentOffset: {
                                y: this.state.scrollY
                            }
                        }
                    }], {
                        listener: (event) => {
                            AppEvents.fire("topBar", this.state.scrollY);
                        },
                    })}
```

AppEvents.fire() is the event which is captured in Parent.
(The captured event then  sets state, then passed as a prop to the  which actually animates.)*

For Tab 2:
The same as tab 1.

*Both are same.

Still doing the optimisation work to this. The animation for me is little jerky in iOS development but it looks great in production iOS app. Android no words everywhere its jerky.

Comment: If i understood you correctly this is exactly what I am doing.

Can share your code so that I can compare it to find out what I am missing.

Comment: Edited my Answer, can you please check it and tell whether it helps.

Comment: Did you face any problem using this method let me know? As we are also improving it.?

Comment: I'm having problems implementing this solution. Can you update this snack https://snack.expo.io/SytBkdBAW, So that I can read your code and implement it.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used react-native, but I can definitely say why you have this issue. I used debugging tool and I figured out that when you clicked on the tab and app calls this portion of the code every time:

```
let translateY = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 600],
      outputRange: [0, -290],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    });

    let TabsTranslateY = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 600],
      outputRange: [0, -290],
      extrapolate: 'clamp'
    });
```

where `this.state.scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)` all the time.

Basically, that means when you will click on the tab and start scrolling, it will scroll from 0. You need to find a solution remember previous state of the Animated.Value or change input/output ranges for animation.

Here is sample how to get click on the tab from App.js:

```
<Tabs removeClippedSubviews={false} screenProps={{animatedScrollY: this.state.scrollY}}
          onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState,action) => {
            console.log(currentState);
          }}
 />
```

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: "where `this.state.scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)` all the time." No that's the initial value. When you start scrolling this value gets updated.

Comment: Would be great if you can implement what you are thinking in this snack https://snack.expo.io/SytBkdBAW and share the updated link. Thanks